# While look results not getting printed

Tags: r

could anyone help me while results are not getting displayed here below

```
col_name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
i <- 1
while (i < length(col_name)) {
    col_name[i]
     i = i+1
 }
```

Expected output

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs a `print`

```
while (i < length(col_name)) {
  print(col_name[i])
 i = i+1
}

#[1] "A"
#[1] "B"
#[1] "C"
```

---

If we need to store the output, initialize an object and update

```
out <- c()
i <- 1
while (i < length(col_name)) { out <- c(out, col_name[i]); i = i+1}
out
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: I know :) But this is something I want to use in shiny. So if I use print. It prints in R console and not in application :)

Comment: @imranp if you want to store the output, create an object. updated the post